# Else If in angular 8

Tags: css, angular, typescript, if-statement

I have two variables `isLoader` and `isError`, when `isLoader` is true an img tag should be visible and when `isError` is true that img  tag should be hide.

```
 if(isLoader == true){
  <img src="#" alt="" style="display:block;">
  }

 else if(isError == true){

  <img src="#" alt="" style="display:none;">
  }
```

How to apply if-else statement in angular?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: Why there is two variable? Don't you set the `isLoader` to *false*? when error occurred?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the style conditionally.

Try like this:

```
<img src="#" alt="" [style.display]="isLoader ? 'block':(isError ? 'none' : '')">
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7j4jv)

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf`

```
  <img *ngIf="isLoader " src="#">
  <img *ngIf="!isLoader && isError" src="#">
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-project-djelqs?file=app/app.component.html